# Application update - Which way to go?

Tags: angular, web-applications, frontend, backend, software-design

we're developing and distributing an enterprise style application using an AngularJS 1.x frontend and a C# / .NET backend. Since AngularJS 1.x is kinda getting old, we're evaluating the workload to update it to Angular4 (at least Angular2, but why not go all the way?).

However, this might be a good point in the project to rethink a few things, especially the frontend framework. I have read several articles and watched a couple of online courses on how to upgrade AngularJS 1.6 to Angular2/4, it appears to me that rewriting the whole frontend in Angular4 might be the cleanest and most recommended way. If so, I might wanna go for another approach and use a whole different frontend framework. But we're living in 2017, and there are loads of them that sound promising and overwhelming at the same time. I have picked a few of my favorites, but I'd rather not mention them here for the sake of a more diverse outcome in the comments.

So guys, if you have any serious recommendations, please do not hesitate to mention them in the comments below, backing your choice by a couple of pros and cons if you don't mind. Any help and insight is much appreciated!

Greetings

Comment: I just want to share that Angular feels like a completely different framework than AngularJs. I have to work with both (old and new project) and every time i have to completely switch my way of thinking. It kind of feels like two different style frameworks like foundation vs bootstrap, minus all the crazy technical stuff. Angular and AngularJs might sound similar but a complete rewrite is necessary so it's not a 'logical' upgrade step per se.

Comment: Appreaciate your insights! Any recommendations on completely different framworks, other than Angular which might fit better?

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a .net backend based project at the moment which the front-end framework was Angualrjs and we ended up with rewriting our entire application slowly to Anuglar2+. What I strongly suggest, in my opinion, you should start considering re-coding in Angular2 instead of trying to convert the previous version.

Our experience shows that it's way better and at the end, you will have much better performant front-end application that can be ported to Ionic or Nativescript in order to build even a mobile application with less effort.

However, it's all up to the team and the company as it could be a large project and become a pricey thought.

Comment: I was wondering did you change the backend or can keep it like it was in AngularJS?

Comment: no Frontend was completely separated from the backend, and basically, you don't need any change on Backend at all. What you need is to reuse the same API in your new front-end code. that's it. It's more front-end works rather than backend.

Comment: and BTW, we still have a mobile app with AngularJs and we are considering rewriting it with Ng4+. which actually basically will be our new Angular app, kinda.

Comment: Why not use Ionic? Ionic is Typescript based to, can use alot of functions out of your Angular2 webApp.

Comment: that's what we wanna do, I meant our old code base is in AngularJs and we are going to have a single code base for both web and mobile app with our Angular2 application as soon as it's completely done.